# How to fit a Beta-Binomial Distribution to a dataset

Tags: distributions, bootstrap, fitting, beta-binomial-distribution

I have a data set which is defined over positive integers and I have reasons to believe it follows a beta-binomial distribution.

I am aware there is the `betabinomial` function that fits such a theoretical distribution to numerical data under the VGAM package, but I am not sure how to use this. I have taken a look at the examples provided by THE documentation but I cannot understand how to adjust them to my case. I have the following questions:

1) Could you please provide a simple example on how to use this function, given a data set?

2) In order to justify such a parsimonious approximation for a data set, I have seen people using bootstrapping among other arguments. Could this be the case here as well? If yes, could you please provide an example on how this would look like?

P.S. My data set is just 1-column.

Thank you.

Comment: For 1), take a look at Example 1 in the help page `?betabinomial`. If this is still unclear, you may want to ask with a minimal working example at StackOverflow in the R tag - here on CV, this will likely be closed as off-topic, since it's about how to run a particular R command. For (2), this is on-topic, but unclear. How specifically did people justify fitting a distribution "by bootstrapping"?